# Calculating grid cells coordinate, based on 2 distance sensors.

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

Imagine an 8x8 grid of cells. In the grid, 1 cell will be "activated" so to say. I need to figure out which one is activated.

The top left corner of the grid is coordinate (0, 0) and the bottom right is (7, 7).

The information that I get, comes from 2 'sensors' placed at (0, 0) and (7, 0). The sensors let me know how far away the activated cell is from the 2 sensors respectively.

**Example**

If coordinate (5, 5) is activated, the sensors will report 11 and 8 respectively. Example drawing:

[image]

**Question**

How can I deduce which cell is activated using only the sensors data (answer should be in the given coordinate system i.e. (0, 0) is top left).

I am simply unable to tackle this problem, and would greatly appreciate someones help.

Answer (score 0):

Call the reading from sensor 1 $S$ and the reading from sensor 2 $T$.

Note that you make $7$ steps horizontally between the two routes.  The rest of the steps are accounted for by the vertical runs.  Each line below the top adds two steps, one for each sensor.  The second coordinate is then $\frac 12(S+T-7)$

You have accounted for $\frac 12(S+T-7)$ of the $S$ steps, so there are $S-\frac 12(S+T-7)=\frac 12(S-T+7) steps in from the left edge.  This is the first coordinate.

In your example, $\frac 12(S+T-7)=\frac 12(11+8-7)=6, \frac 12(S-T+7)=\frac 12(11-8+7)=5$ so the target cell is $(5,6)$.  This does not match your diagram because you counted a step inside the target cell.  I would start counting at $0$ in the target cell.  Using your picture I would report $S=10, T=7$, making the target cell $(5,5)$